# Rails :include doesn't include

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, include, nested-resources, active-relation

My models:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :emails
  has_many :websites
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :emails, :websites
  attr_accessible :prefix, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :suffix,
                  :nickname, :organization, :job_title, :department, :birthday,
                  :emails_attributes
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  validates_presence_of :account
  validates_format_of :account, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
  attr_accessible :contact_id, :account, :label
end
```

If I run the following query, the `emails` are returned as expected:

```
c = Contact.find(3)
  Contact Load (3.2ms)  SELECT `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` LIMIT 1
=> #<Contact id: 3, prefix: nil, first_name: "Micah", middle_name: nil, last_name: "Alcorn", suffix: nil, nickname: nil, organization: nil, job_title: nil, department: nil, birthday: nil, created_at: "2011-07-04 23:50:04", updated_at: "2011-07-04 23:50:04">

c.emails
  Email Load (4.4ms)  SELECT `emails`.* FROM `emails` WHERE `emails`.`contact_id` = 3
=> [#<Email id: 3, contact_id: 3, account: "not@real.address", label: "work", created_at: "2011-07-04 23:50:04", updated_at: "2011-07-04 23:50:04">]
```

However, attempting to `:include` the relationship does not:

```
c = Contact.find(3, :include => :emails)
  Contact Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` WHERE `contacts`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Email Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `emails`.* FROM `emails` WHERE `emails`.`contact_id` IN (3)
=> #<Contact id: 3, prefix: nil, first_name: "Micah", middle_name: nil, last_name: "Alcorn", suffix: nil, nickname: nil, organization: nil, job_title: nil, department: nil, birthday: nil, created_at: "2011-07-04 23:50:04", updated_at: "2011-07-04 23:50:04">
```

As you can see, the SQL is being executed, but the emails are not being returned. I intend to return all contacts with each containing email(s), so `:joins` won't do any good. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emails are there. Did you try `c.emails`? You will find that the emails will be there without Rails doing an additional DB query.

The thing that `:include` does is called eager loading, which basically means Rails will try a best effort method of prepopulating your objects with their relations, so that when you actually ask for the relation no additional DB queries are needed.

See the section "**Eager loading of associations**" here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

You might also want to check out this RailsCast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the purpose of the method. I was expecting it to return the `emails` inside of each `contact` alongside the attributes. My goal is to provide a JSON representation of all contacts in my index action, including the nested email attributes. Any advice?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "inside of each contact". I think you might have misuderstood, but this is still what you want to do for your case. It just preloads all the emails in the best possible way for you. So when you do `Contact.find(:all, :include => :emails)` you will get the emails attached to each contact (through the association, not as direct attributes in the contact). After this why not just do this: `Contact.find(:all, :include => :emails).to_json(:include => :emails)`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Additional `to_json()` tricks described here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json